# Anti-Aliasing of UIBezierpath with RoundedRect

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I created a rounded rect with UIBezierpath which works very good for me. There is only one problem the rounded edges of the rect have a kind of aliasing effect.
Here is a picture [image: Aliasing on corners]

I create the rounded rect like this:

```
CGFloat radius = 12;
CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y+(self.bounds.size.height/heightFactor), self.bounds.size.width-shadowConst, self.bounds.size.height-(self.bounds.size.height/heightFactor)-shadowConst);

CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width-(self.bounds.size.width/widthFactor), self.bounds.origin.y+(self.bounds.size.height/(heightFactor*2)), (self.bounds.size.width/widthFactor)-shadowConst, (self.bounds.size.height/heightFactor));

UIBezierPath *result =
[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: frame1 cornerRadius:radius];
[result appendPath:
 [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: frame2 cornerRadius:radius]];
[result fill];
[result addClip];
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient2, CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(0, self.bounds.size.height), 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see it could be one of two issues:

You're drawing with colours that appear weird when combined. Bright green on top of grey may make it look weird.

Also, for your shadowConst and heightFactor, be careful that you're not dividing so the size, or placement of the frame is 0.5. So for example, if whatever the size you want for the width is equals `[size].5`, it will draw will a blurry side. Same if you set the x or y value for the frame to `[value].5`

Comment: I tried to draw it without the color. Same aliasing is happening...

I don't really understand what you mean with the constants. ShadowConst is just an Integer with the value of 3 and heightFactor is also an integer constant. How could this cause the aliasing?
edit: My guess would be that it's something internal in the drawing mechanism.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your comment until now. But saw you accepted it, so I reckon you figured it out based on my tip :)